# Polygon.contains() throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, list, thread-safety, polygon, synchronized

Some context, I'm developing an Asteroids game

So, my Asteroid is a Polygon (Java built-in object) and a bullet is simply a point.
When I'm trying to detect a collision between an asteroid and a bullet I'm using `Polygon.contains(x,y)` with the bullet coordinates.
But for some reason, I get NullPointerException when using this method *but I only get the exception sometimes* 99% of the time everything works perfectly and then I get this exception.
I get this a exception when I'm shooting a bullet and if the exception is thrown the bullet will stop (the bullet is a thread so the thread died).

Here's the relevant code:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= Math.ceil(l); i++) {
            try {
                t = i / (l - extension);
                y = (int) ((t * (cursorPos.y - initY)) + initY);
                x = (int) ((t * (cursorPos.x - initX)) + initX);
                if (!PlayerPanel.meteorList.isEmpty()) {
                    synchronized (PlayerPanel.meteorList) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < PlayerPanel.meteorList.size(); j++) {
                            if (PlayerPanel.meteorList.get(j).shapes[PlayerPanel.meteorList.get(j).selectedMeteor].contains(x, y)) { // Line 39
                                PlayerPanel.meteorList.get(j).shapes[PlayerPanel.meteorList.get(j).selectedMeteor].invalidate();
                                PlayerPanel.playerScore+=10;
                                PlayerPanel.scoreLabel.setText("Score: " + PlayerPanel.playerScore);
                                synchronized (PlayerPanel.bulletList) {
                                    PlayerPanel.bulletList.remove(this);
                                }
                                PlayerPanel.meteorList.remove(PlayerPanel.meteorList.get(j));
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.sleep(1);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

The Asteroids are being stored inside a list and same goes for the bullets

The exception:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Polygon.getBoundingBox(Polygon.java:335)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Polygon.contains(Polygon.java:398)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Polygon.contains(Polygon.java:364)
    at Bullet.run(Bullet.java:39)
```

Answer (score 2):

If PlayerPanel.meteorList or PlayerPanel.bulletList are not thread safe collections (like Vector) consider using Collections.synchronizedList:

```
 List list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList(...));
 
 synchronized(list){
       //...
 }
```

Comment: Thats so cool I didn't know about that- but I'm using ```synchronize()``` so I think I'll get to the same result (do I?)

Comment: I updated the sample, which includes synchronized. Unfortunately, in your case, synchronize not do what you expect.

Comment: Oh good to know :) but can you explain what's the differences between the two?

Comment: UPDATE:
just got the exception again (and I'm using ```synchronizedList```)